# ubuntu will run but wont install from disk

Tags: 12.10

I downloaded ubuntu and burned to disk. booted up using the disk and Ubuntu will load. but it wont install. I'll click the install icon select my internet and click continue. then nothing. the hour glass goes and goes but nothing.  I'm using a dell inspiron 1545. Windows no longer works on this pc. I was trying to run Ubuntu as a hassle free alternative.

Comment: Boot to the disk, click "Try Ubuntu", open a terminal (it's in the Dash), and run this command: `sudo fdisk -l`. Edit your answer with the output of the command (you can open up this question in Firefox in the "Try Ubuntu" section to make the copy-paste a little easier).

Answer (score 0):

You could also boot the disk and choose install Ubuntu to kick off ubiquity without the live environment and see if it will install that way.